# DS1302 realtime clock - pulldowns required?

Tags: rtc, pulldown

I'm trying to wire up a DS1302 realtime clock, one of these:

[image: DS1302]

to a parallax propeller board.

The [datasheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1302.pdf) says (page 4) that pulldowns are integrated into each of the main lines (looks like 3 needed to drive this thing).

This [post](http://forums.parallax.com/showthread.php/100787-interfacing-the-DS1302-to-the-prop) mentions that pulldowns are required, so that seems to conflict.

I'm assuming that what the datasheet says is that the pulldowns are internal and I can just connect these 3 lines directly to pins on the propeller.  Does that seem right?

Comment: The data sheet says that the chip has internal pull-downs, so you don't need to add them.

Comment: Actually, the port you refer to states that pull-**ups** are required, not pull-downs. I'm not real familiar with the chip, but I see no reason for any pull-ups, except maybe on the Data pin. this would allow you to run the processor's pin in open-collector mode, to avoid the possibility of a programming error driving the processor's pin the opposite direction as the DS1302, possibly damaging either.

Comment: Tracking and thanks for the replies.  Will try it withou pullups or pulldowns and see how that works out.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, works fine without any pullups or pulldowns.

RANDOM NOTE: Does very strange things if the power (VCC) pin is not connected.  I managed to get everything wired correctly the first time except I had a loose connection on the power pin, and because it has it's own battery thing is still on but gives somewhat systematic but garbage data.  Very confusing until I figured out what was happening.